# JQuery reads old version of file

Tags: html, jquery

So I am working on a project for my rPi which collects network speed information and logs it in a webserver locally. The Script is working all fine, but for some reason the JQuery code runs differently in Windows (where it read a file and displayed correctly) as in my rpi. Let me explain: The file is modified every so often to change what is displayed in the webserver so it is up-to-date. For some reason, without modifying anything, the JQuery code reads the file incorrectly (old data after changing the file, even after restarting the whole program). I have even tried to move the file out of the dir it was in, to verify that there wasn't any other duplicate file, and there wasn't another.

This is the HTML file

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src='jquery-3.6.0.min.js'></script>
<script>
    $.get('./assets/current.txt', function(data) {
        var items = data.split(',');
        $('#date').html(items[0]);
        $('#ping').html(items[1]);
        $('#download').html(items[2]);
        $('#upload').html(items[3]);


    })
</script>
<p>Date: <span id="date"></span></p>
<p>ping: <span id="ping"></span> ms</p>
<p>dowload: <span id="download"></span> MB/s</p>
<p>upload: <span id="upload"></span> MB/s</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it because of browser cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour is possible if browser is caching the file. In order to force the file from server all the time extend the url as `$.get('./assets/current.txt?_u='+Date.now(), function (){...})`

Comment: Thanks! It was indeed browser cache.